# Python function returning incorrect value

Tags: python, python-idle

I have recently decided to start learning basic python...
I am creating a simple python File class, similar to the one used in the .NET framework.

So far, I have the following code:

```
import os

class File:
    def __init__(self, filename=""):
        self.path = filename
        self.pathwithoutfilename, self.extwithdot = os.path.splitext(filename)
        self.ext = self.extwithdot.replace(".", "")

    def exists():
        rbool = False
        if(os.path.exists(self.path)):
            rbool = True
        else:
            rbool = False

        return rbool

    def getPath():
        return self.path


test = File("/var/test.ad")
print(test.path)
print(test.extwithdot)
print(test.ext)
print(test.getPath)
```

However, when I run this code, (I am using python 2.7 on Ubuntu) it prints this for the test.getPath function:

```
<bound method File.getPath of <__main__.File instance at 0x3e99b00>>
```

I have been changing and editing my code for a while now but I have not had any success... I would like the getPath function to return the `self.path` value set earlier...

Thanks

Rodit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test.getPath` will return the location of the function or instance of class (in case of a method). You want to add parens to *call* the function

```
print(test.getPath())
```

Note, as pointed out by Lukas Graf, your class implementation needs to pass the `self` identifier when defining methods if they are to be able to be called from an instantiated object, i.e.

```
def getPath(self):
    ...
```

This will allow you to do

```
test = File(parameter)
test.getPath()
```

Comment: "perands" - you mean "parens"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when I call it like that, I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rodit/Desktop/Python/FileClass.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(test.getPath())
TypeError: getPath() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Also, the methods need to take `self` as their first argument.

Comment: @LukasGraf Thanks this solved my problem! Post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @rodit I was counting on C.B. to edit that into his answer, and he already did ;-)

Comment: @rodit Also, just `self` would not solve the problem.  Your larger problem was the lack of parenthesis.

Comment: @SethMMorton I know... But it was the self that solved my final problem so I credited it last.